# Strange output from C++ in Linux Terminal

Tags: c++, linux

I've recently started learning programming using the C++ language. I wrote a simple program that is supposed to reverse a string which I compile in the Terminal using gcc/g++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string reverse_string(string str)
{
    string newstring = ""; 
    int index = -1;
    while (str.length() != newstring.length())
    {
        newstring.append(1, str[index]);
        index -= 1;
    }
    return newstring;
}

int main()
{
    string x;
    cout << "Type something: "; cin >> x;
    string s = reverse_string(x);
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've rewritten it multiple times but I always get the same output:

```
Type something: banana
��
```

Has anyone had a problem like this or know how to fix it?

Comment: Some language string classes allow accessing a negative index of a string, and measure from the end.  C++ `std::string` is not one of those.

Comment: As mentioned below, `std::reverse` works great, or `std::string rev(fwd.rbegin(), fwd.rend());`

Answer (score 2):

Your code initializes `index` to -1, and then uses `str[index]` but a negative index has no rational meaning in C++.  Try instead initializing it like so:

```
index = str.length() - 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I was only using a negative because I'm too familiar with Python.

Answer (score 2):

I can see several issues with your code. Firstly, you are initializing `index` to `-1`, and then decrementing it. Maybe you meant `auto index = str.length()-1;`?

I recommend you look at [std::reverse](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse), which will do the job you're after.

Your main function then becomes:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x;
    cout << "Type something: ";
    cin >> x;
    reverse(x.begin(), x.end());
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you really want to write your own reverse function, I recommend iterators over array indices. See [std::reverse_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) for another approach.

**Note**, the above will simply reverse the order of bytes within the string. Whilst this is fine for ASCII, it will not work for multi-byte encodings, such as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a memory debugger like valgrind.
It's a good practice to scan your binary with it, and will make you save so much time.